# How parse JSON data into ListView

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview

I would like to visualize the Json data on a listview, but I don't know how to do it ... I tried to use a TextView to verify the correct passage of the data and it seems to work, but I would need to display them on the listView ... ideas?

```html
{"Esito":true,"Dati":[{"id":"357","id_utente":"16","nome_prodotto":"cozze"},{"id":"358","id_utente":"16","nome_prodotto":"riso"},{"id":"362","id_utente":"16","nome_prodotto":"patate"},{"id":"366","id_utente":"16","nome_prodotto":"cozze"},{"id":"367","id_utente":"16","nome_prodotto":null}]}
```

```
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.G[enter image description here][1]ET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {

                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Dati");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject dato = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String id = dato.getString("id");
                            String id_utente = dato.getString("id_utente");
                            String nome_prodotto = dato.getString("nome_prodotto");

                            mTextViewResult.append(id + ", " + id_utente +  ", " + nome_prodotto +  "\n\n");
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: use recycler view instead of listview and check example for parsing data to receyler view...

Comment: create a model class, and parse yout JSON into it. Then iterate through your JSONArray and collect your model into the list. Then set this list as a source of RecyclerView.

Comment: please share JSON format

Answer (score 0):

Just make new object class and collect data to list :

```
class YourObiekt {
private String id;
private String idUtente;
private String nomeProdotto;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getIdUtente() {
    return idUtente;
}

public void setIdUtente(String idUtente) {
    this.idUtente = idUtente;
}

public String getNomeProdotto() {
    return nomeProdotto;
}

public void setNomeProdotto(String nomeProdotto) {
    this.nomeProdotto = nomeProdotto;
}
```

}

```
 List<YourObiekt> yourObiektList = new ArrayList<YourObiekt>();
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {

                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Dati");


                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject dato = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        YourObiekt yo = new YourObiekt();

                        yo.setId(dato.getString("id"));
                        yo.setIdUtente(dato.getString("id_utente"));
                        yo.setNomeProdotto(dato.getString("nome_prodotto"));

                        yourObiektList.add(yo);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

And now you get yourObiektList as data for your listView

Comment: Hi, I followed your suggestion, but I didn't understand how to enter the data in the listview ... I did this:   
 
                            lstView = findViewById(R.id.lstView);

                            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yourObiektList);
                            lstView.setAdapter(adapter);